# dismiss progress bar after a set period of time?

Tags: android, progress-bar

is there any way to set timer for the progress bar? for example wait for 10 second and then dismiss the progress bar? I would appreciate if someone could give me a simple code on that.

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) in the UI-Thread and then call it via [sendMessageDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#sendMessageDelayed%28android.os.Message,%20long%29).

```
...
final Handler h = new Handler() {
  @Override
  public void handleMessage(Message message) {
    mProgressBar.dismiss();
  }     
};
h.sendMessageDelayed(new Message(), 10000);
...
```

This code is not testet.

Comment: more efficient to use `h.obtainMessage()` than constructing a new message. Granted you are only creating this once, but if this code is called multiple times, as I would assume he would do for lengthy operations. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#obtainMessage()

Comment: You are right this could be more efficient to use a Message from the pool then create a new one.

Comment: also Thanks to Russ or the recommended amendment :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) class.

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;

public class someClass implements Handler.Callback {
    public static final int MSG_HIDE_PBAR = 0;
    static final long PBAR_DELAY = 10 * 1000; //Delay is is milliseconds

    //Probably should initialize this in your creation code (onCreate if activity)
    //and likewise set it to null when destroyed (onDestroy if activity)
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler(this); 

    public void showPbar(){
        //Show your progress bar here
        mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(MSG_HIDE_PBAR, PBAR_DELAY);
    }

    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg){
        switch (msg.what){
            case MSG_HIDE_PBAR:
                //hide your progress bar here, call postInvalidate instead of
                //invalidate because we are in a different thread
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Quick: Yes, Dirty: Yes, gets the job done: Yes

You could probably accomplish the same with an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) with a sleep call or a loop checking the clock. `Handler` seems cleaner to me.

Comment: this is impressive man, I will try it and will let you know how did I get on with that. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

yes you can use `Thread` and [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) for dismiss after 10s as:

```
public void myThread() {
    Thread th = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (mRunning) {
                    Thread.sleep(10L);//10s wait
                    YourCurrentActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            //DISMISS PROGRESS BAR HERE
                            mRunning = false;
                        }
                    });
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }
        }
    };
    th.start();
}
```

Comment: Cool, I have no idea what it is going to do. However I will try it and will let you know. Many thanks :)